# How to say in English: You can trust and no need to think about it any more?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to take care of something. I tell my friend I will give you "{{missing_word}}". or you can have "{{missing_word}]"

I mean. That he can trust and believe that everything will works well, and he don't need to think about it.

In Hebrew we say "quiet head".  (ראש שקט). There is a word for it in English?

Comment: "Don't give it a second thought," perhaps?

Comment: You could say that you will put his mind at ease about it; that's quite parallel to the Hebrew expression. But it sounds a bit odd. We most commonly use that expression about past or hypothetical situations/actions, and mostly about our _own_ minds. So if you say that you'll fix it, not to worry, then it would be normal enough for him to say, “Well, that [= your agreeing to fix it] puts my mind at ease”. But it sounds a bit odd for you to say, “I'll put your mind at ease and fix it, don't worry”.

Comment: 'Confidence' is the word.

Answer (score 6):

Consider "**peace of mind**", which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peace%20of%20mind) as

> a feeling of being safe or protected

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to my mind is "*[You have my word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8261/whats-the-difference-between-you-have-my-word-and-i-promise)*".

There are a lot of other ways to say this :

- You can trust me / have trust in me
- You can rest assured

> [**rest assured**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/rest-assured)
>
> To be certain that something will happen
>
> *You can rest assured that you’re going to get a good deal.*
>
> **Note: Used to make someone feel safe or less worried about something**.

Or, as @JanusBahsJacquet said in a comment, "*put his mind at ease*" is also a good answer, even though it's better suited to describe a situation rather than directly say it to someone.